# Ionic - Add one quality check for the picture

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, frameworks

I need check the "good quality" when the user upload one image (from camera to gallery), I need check that blur and Brightness / contrast will be the correct.. exist any way to check this fields? (I need check with Ionic)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You should post what you've tried so far. Learn [ask] a good question and post [mcve].

Comment: I don't tried nothing, I don't know how to do this.. because i don't know how check if one image is a good quality. Only i check the width and height.. this part it's ok, y put a min resolution.. but i don't have idea how check if image has blur or has little ilumination. And thanks for the welcome!